# ListBox Can not Showing BindingList Data, showing object name instead

Tags: c#, listbox

So i'm trying to make a windows form application, and i want to make a Transaction Windows Form.

So I'd like to create some kind of shopping cart, that it would appear on the listbox whenever the user press "Add" Button

I tried to Show the shopping cart to the listbox by using BindingList, the problem is the listbox itself showing the object of BindingList item instead

the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pertemuan03
{
    public partial class Transaction : Form
    {
        class Cart{
           public string ProductID { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int quantity  { get; set; }

        };
        BindingList<Cart> shoppingList = new BindingList<Cart>();
        public Transaction()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            listBox1.DataSource = shoppingList;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            shoppingList.Add(new Cart {ProductID = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),name= textBox1.Text,quantity = (int)numericUpDown1.Value});
            listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = shoppingList;
        }


    }
}
```

it showing like this
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaQcj.png)

Comment: You should help the listbox to display your objects by giving your object class a proper ToString method!

Comment: Override the ToString method in the Cart to format the information the way you want to display.  If I'm right, you're seeing the default 'ToString' behavor for 'object'.

Comment: Another option might be to set the DataSource to a specific property of the object.  Not as sure about this one, but it depends on how much you want the object to render in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you have to set the display member property. (cfr [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
        BindingList<TestType> testList = new BindingList<TestType>();
        testList.Add(new TestType() { NameToDisplay = "MyName" });
        myListBox.DataSource = testList;
        myListBox.DisplayMember = "NameToDisplay";
```